# Haskell: Sorting a List of Trees

Tags: list, sorting, haskell

I have a list of trees that have associated numerical values (we can treat it like sorting a list of Ints for this case) and I want to sort the whole list from highest to lowest and return the new sorted list. How do I do this? I have encountered the built in list sorting functions such as sortBy but I don't understand how to implement it.

I'm also new to coding in general if it wasn't obvious ;)

Comment: You can just implement or derive Ord for your tree structure

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Sorting a list of trees in general, or getting the highest-to-lowest ordering?

Comment: @melpomene Sorting in general, i don't understand how the functions work or how to apply them.

Comment: @DanielSanchez I don't know how to do that though, or what deriving Ord really means.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can write your function

```
score :: Tree -> Int
```

providing a score for each of your trees. The score above is an `Int`, but any other ordered type can do as a score.

Then, you can use

```
sortBy (flip $ comparing score) myListOfTree
```

to sort according to the score. Remember to import `Data.Ord` for `comparing`.

---

Note that this can compute the score more than once. If your score function is expensive, you might want instead to precompute the scores as follows:

```
map snd . sortBy (flip $ comparing fst) . map (\t -> (score t, t)) $ myListOfTree
```

---

Another option is to define your own comparison function directly

```
compareTree :: Tree -> Tree -> Ordering
compareTree t1 t2 | someCondition       = LT   -- t1 <  t2
                  | someOtherCondiction = EQ   -- t1 == t2
                  | otherwise           = GT   -- t1 >  t2
```

where in the conditions you can use your score function, if you want.

Then use `sortBy compareTree` to do sort in ascending order, or `sortBy (flip compareTree)` for the descending sort.

If this ordering it the only "natural" ordering for your `Tree` type, you can even declare it such:

```
instance Ord Tree where
   compare = compareTree
```

(Note however that this approach will call `compareTree` many times, one for every comparison, possibly computing the score over and over. Hence, the `map` solution shown above might still be preferred.)

Comment: This gives results in ascending, not descending order.

Comment: @melpomene Ah I missed that. Thanks.

Comment: This worked! The guarded expression was one of my first thoughts for this problem, but the first option is working perfectly for its purpose. I see that sortBy has type (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a], could you explain the first bracketed argument? especially in relation to the example

Comment: @420fedoras The first argument of `sortBy` must be of type `a -> a -> Ordering`, i.e. it must be a binary function. In your case, such function takes two trees (the `a -> a -> ` part in the type) and return the result of the comparison (the `Ordering`). `Ordering` is just a simple type with exactly tree values `LT,EQ,GT` for the three possible results of comparison.

Comment: @chi okay that makes sense, but what are the two arguments in `sortBy (flip $ comparing score)` ? or does it just take elements from the provided list as the argument? also when an element is sorted does it get put back into the list or does it get put into a new list? Like does it work similar to selection sort does?

Comment: @420fedoras `sortBy` takes the arguments from the input list, and feeds them (two-by-two) to the comparison function. The resulting sorted elements are put into a new list -- there's no way to modify or mutate the original list in Haskell.